# OpenSCAP SCE script in Source DataStream file

Tags: openscap

I am new to OpenSCAP, and have a query about SCE scripts and the DataStream format.

The SCE [documentation](https://www.open-scap.org/features/other-standards/sce/) for OpenSCAP states:

> The SCE scripts can be part of a Source DataStream. DataStream is a format that packs multiple SCAP components into a single file.

How can a shell script be encapsulated into a DataStream file and used within an xccdf Rule definition? I have been unable to find any examples of this being done and the documentation does not provide an example or syntax.

[This](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/open-scap-list/2016-June/msg00005.html) thread suggests that there is an 'extended-components' tag but I am still unaware of the usage of this tag.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this, but I would suggest you start with

```
$ oscap ds sds-create INPUT_XCCDF_FILE.xml OUTPUT_SDS_FILE.xml
```

IIRC, `oscap` will take SCE scripts referenced from that `XCCDF_FILE` (relative filesystem path) and put them into the datastream.

Comment: This has resolved my issue. I'm not sure why the shell script location appeared to be inaccessible for oscap however using the above command to embed it has resolved the issue and my SCE script is run, thank you.